# Does HTML need to be encoded when passed back in JSON?

Tags: html, json, grails

When passing HTML back through a response in JSON format, does it need to get encoded?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You would pass the HTML code in a string, so any quotation marks and backslashes in the code would have to be encoded.

Example:

```
<div onclick="alert('Line 1\nLine2');">show</div>
```

would be encoded into a string like this:

```
"<div onclick=\"alert('Line 1\\nLine2');\">show</div>"
```

and for example put in a JSON object representation like this:

```
{"html":"<div onclick=\"alert('Line 1\\nLine2');\">show</div>"}
```

Comment: In addition, any control characters must be escaped. I'd only expect to find \r, \n, and \t, but that doesn't preclude others. Whatever JSON framework you're using should be able to do this properly for you.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer "no" JSON does not need to be encoded when passed back in JSON.  JSON object should be DIRECTLY parsable by a javascript engine. Check the following:

- [JSON Standard](http://www.json.org/)
- [JSON Lint](http://www.jsonlint.com/)